# ContentDocumentLink filter error on ContentDocumentID using IN clause

Tags: apex, trigger, content

I have to get all the "linked" records from a Document (`ContentDocument`) and then filter only the `Events` from them using the following apex.

```
// Query ContentDocumentLink object for the 'Event' link and apply 'WHERE' filter of the above map's contentdocument id.
Map<id, Event> mapEvent = new Map<id, Event>();
Set<Id> EventIds = new Set<Id>();
for(ContentDocumentLink cdlForEvent: [SELECT ContentDocumentID, LinkedEntity.type, LinkedEntityId 
                                    FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                                    WHERE ContentDocumentID IN: mapOfContentVersion.keySet()])
{
    if(cdlForEvent.LinkedEntity.Type == 'Event')
    {
        EventIds.add(cdlForEvent.LinkedEntityId);
    }
}
```

I'm using `ContentDocumentId` filter, from a `contentversion` map but it is giving me following error

> Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a
>   single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals
>   operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.

Interestingly, if I provided hard-coded values using `IN` clause then it accepts it. But I have to make it run in the apex and it has to be dynamic. Following soql works

```
for(ContentDocumentLink cdlForEvent: 
                [SELECT ContentDocumentID, LinkedEntity.type, LinkedEntityId 
                FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                WHERE ContentDocumentID IN ('06923000000CqHNaxy', '06923000000CqHNAA0')])
```

I dont understand what is missing. How should I get all the related linked entity records and then filter Events from them?

Comment: Can you log the value of  mapOfContentVersion.keySet() - what does it return?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

the solution is to add your keySet() from Map to a new Set() and use that in the query filter using IN:

Ex:

```
Set<Id> newSet = mapOfContentVersion.keySet();


[SELECT ContentDocumentID, LinkedEntity.type, LinkedEntityId 
                                    FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                                    WHERE ContentDocumentID IN: newSet ]
```

**This worked for me today

Comment: It does but why? map.keySet() and a set<id> , aren't they both same thing?

Comment: In a unit test, this works only if you execute the query one time but not two times before StartTest. The second time I get the same error. 
After StopTest I can query again filtering by the new set without issues.
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Not sure how this one works, didn't work for me unfortunately. Exec. Anonymous Code:  `Map<Id, ContentVersion> mapCV = new Map<Id, ContentVersion>();
Set<Id> setId = mapCV.keyset();
List<ContentDocumentLink> listCDL = [SELECT LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, Visibility 
                                     FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN: setId];`

Answer (score 11):

I encountered the same error in my query for ContentDocumentLink records:

**"Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator."**

But the issue turned out to be that my Set was empty.  The error message was misleading.

I resolved the issue by checking if my Set had values before proceeding with the query for ContentDocumentLinks.

As an example:

```
Set<Id> newSet = mapOfContentVersion.keySet();
if(EventIds.size() > 0){
     [SELECT ContentDocumentID, LinkedEntity.type, LinkedEntityId 
                                    FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                                    WHERE ContentDocumentID IN: newSet ]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This must be a recent update (this year), because I had code working filtering on a Set with no problem, and suddenly noticed today it no longer worked. I resolved the issue by first casting the Set to a List; see below.

```
    // Get content document links
    List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocLinks = [
        SELECT
            ContentDocumentId
        FROM
            ContentDocumentLink
        WHERE
            LinkedEntityId IN :stipRecordIds
    ];
    Set<Id> contentDocIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(ContentDocumentLink contentDocLink : contentDocLinks) {
        contentDocIds.add(contentDocLink.ContentDocumentId);
    }
    List<Id> contentDocIdList = new List<Id>(contentDocIds);

    // Get the actual files
    List<ContentVersion> contentVersions = [
        SELECT
            Id,
            ContentUrl
        FROM
            ContentVersion
        WHERE
            ContentDocumentId IN :contentDocIdList
            AND
            IsLatest = True
    ];
```

Comment: I believe this is something with Content specific objects. See my comments above to Cropredy's reply. Never worked for me until I changed it to List<id>.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @harish answer, the underlying problem is [similar to using `object.field` notation as bind variables in dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm?search_text=bind%20variables) - even though the use case is static SOQL

**For static SOQL - does not work**

```
[select COUNT() from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = :someObj.Id]
```

**For static SOQL, does work**

```
ID filter = someObj.ID;
[select COUNT() from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = :filter]
```

That is, `filter` works because it is a simple variable and not located via an object reference (e.g. `someObj.Id`)

Comment: recently I encountered another very weird [issue](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139007/fetching-all-the-content-notes-related-to-an-event) where I was not getting results for `map.keySet()` or `Set<id>` even if I put them in a variable but it worked for `List<id>`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if [this top voted answer workaround](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/128562/38952) is valid anymore. It didn't work for my below Exec. anonymous code. Feel free to copy-paste and try.

```
Map<Id, ContentVersion> mapCV = new Map<Id, ContentVersion>();
Set<Id> setId = mapCV.keyset();
List<ContentDocumentLink> listCDL = [SELECT LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, Visibility 
                                     FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN: setId];
```

**Below is another working solution**,

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> listCDL = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();

if (!mapCV.isEmpty()){

listCDL = [SELECT LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, Visibility FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN: mapCV.keySet()];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set< Id > newSet =new Set< Id >; 

for(Id id:mapOfContentVersion.keySet())

{

     newSet.add(id);

}


[SELECT ContentDocumentID, LinkedEntity.type, LinkedEntityId 
                                    FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                                    WHERE ContentDocumentID =: newSet ]
```

Comment: Code dump answers here are discouraged. Any code which answers the question should be accompanied by at least a brief explanation.