# map.keySet() or Set<Id> not returning content notes related to an Event

Tags: soql, contentversion

**Requirement**

I have to fetch all the content Notes that are associated to events created after 01-Aug-2016.

**Logic path**

I have taken the following path to get to content notes

- fetch events
- find the Link via ContentDocumentLink object by passing them Event ids fetched in step-1
- fetch ContentVersion by passing ContentDocumentIds retrieved in step-2
- check each contentversion record by looking at their fileType to filter out only notes (SNOTE).

**Code**

```
Set<id> ev=(new Map<Id, Event>([SELECT id from Event where CreatedDate > 2016-08-01T00:00:00Z])).keySet();
Map<id, ContentDocumentLink> cdlMap = new Map<id, ContentDocumentLink>();
//ContentDocumentLink[] cdlList =[SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN : ev];
Set<id> contentDocumentIdSet = new set<id>();
for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: [SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN : ev])
{
    cdlMap.put(cdl.ContentDocumentId, cdl);
    contentDocumentIdSet.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId);
}

system.debug('cdl keys > ' + contentDocumentIdSet );
List<ContentVersion> cvMap = new List<ContentVersion>([SELECT Title, FileType, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE  ContentDocumentId IN:contentDocumentIdSet]);
system.debug('cdlMap ' + cdlMap.size() + '| cvMap > ' + cvMap.size());
```

**Problem**

ContentVersion list (cvMap) is not returning anything.

- I tried passing `cdlMap.keySet()` didn't work.
- I then created a `Set<id>` and passed the map keyset to it and then supplied it to the SOQL, that didn't work either.
- and now I tried the above code to created a set in loop and provide it in SOQL. Not working.

  If I hardcode ContentDocumentId to SOQL single or multiple, it is working. I wonder why it is not working in this case.

Comment: If you don't have permission to view the ContentVersions that you're trying to query, then that would explain what you're seeing.

If they are privately shared (and not with you), and you're using the Dev Console to test, then you will be able to get the ContentDocumentLink objects, but querying on ContentVersion will return nothing.

Comment: They are publicly shared with 'AllUsers'. and when i soql on individual ids on contentversion I get the records but not when I supply them in the form of a set<id> using IN clause.

Comment: That's really odd. I adapted your code slightly so that it would work on one of my orgs and it did work (when I had access to the CV). I only really changed the for-loop:
for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = '06920000002qcCo']). So it doesn't look like something fundamental to SF

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my question. If I supply hardcoded Ids, just like you did, even the IN clause work fine. But if i try to supply map.keySet() or a Set<id> to pass the ids to the soql dynamically, it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code works courtesy of [Ausin Mueller](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsProfile?communityId=09aF00000004HMG&userId=005F0000006f58M&showHeader=false).

```
Map< Id, Event > ev = new Map< Id, Event > ( [SELECT Id FROM Event WHERE CreatedDate > 2016-08-01T00:00:00Z] );

if( !ev.isEmpty() ) {

List< Id > cdl = new List< Id >();
Set< Id > events = ev.keySet();

for ( ContentDocumentLink c : [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :events] ) {

    cdl.add( c.ContentDocumentId );

}

if ( !cdl.isEmpty() ) {

    List< ContentVersion > notes = [SELECT Title, FileType, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :cdl AND IsLatest = true AND IsDeleted = false AND FileType = 'SNOTE'];

}

}
```

One thing that boggles my mind:
Why `Set<id>` or `map.keySet()`didn't work while `List<id>` worked. Anyone who can explain this to me?