# SOQL Querry Error for ContentDocumentLink

Tags: apex, contentdocumentlink

> Error: Implementation restriction: Implementation restriction:
>   ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on
>   ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or
>   multiple Id's using the IN operator.requires a filter by a single Id
>   on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or
>   multiple Id's using the IN operator.

Code:

```
public static List<AttachWrapper> getAttachment(Id parentId){

        //attachmentList = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, ParentID FROM Attachment WHERE ParentID =:parentId];
         ConDocLnk= [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: parentId ];}
```

I've faced error while fetching ContentDocumentLink records with setting filter as its parent id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ContentDocumentLink filter error on ContentDocumentID using IN clause](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128255/contentdocumentlink-filter-error-on-contentdocumentid-using-in-clause)